# outputting float array values does not work as intended

Tags: c++, arrays

First of all, I am sorry if this is very trivial question. I am new to `C++` and am doing very basic tests. I have checked a couple of tutorials about pointers and arrays.. nevertheless I have a problem which doesn't go away no matter what I try.

The problem is that, after I set values to `float` type array - all values are being read as 0 (zeros). When absolutely the same operation is done to `int` array, then values are being read correctly.

Code:

```
int N = 3;

int* x = new int[N];
float* y = new float[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    x[i] = (int)i;
    y[i] = (float)i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    printf("%d\n", y[i]);
}
```

Output:

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 0
>
> 2
>
> 0

How do I properly assign 0 1 and 2 values to `float` type array of size `3` and read these values afterwards, in a loop?

Comment: Use `%f` in `printf`

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: "I am new to C++" ... please do learn C++ and use `std::vector`/`std::array` and iostreams. Your code is missing roughly 30 years of improving the way we can write C++ ;)

Comment: @YSC I am also voting to close this question. Should I just delete it or leave it be?

Comment: @user463035818 agreed. My main expertise is C#. Now I need a bit of `C++` in order to create a working `C++/CLI` assembly. I don't think I will ever know this language as most of the people here :)

Comment: @Alex once someone answered your question and got rep' over it, it would be incorrect to delete your question as it would remove that rep' earned. I see you've accepted their answer, which is the one thing to do. Eventually, this question will be closed, but won't be deleted.

Comment: @Alex, @user463035818 is right. The code you are writing is outdated, and looks more like `c` than `c++`. Please have a look at the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). These guidelines are unfortunately far from complete, but should still give you a rough outline what is possible with `c++` nowadays and how it is recommended to write `c++`.

Comment: @jan.sende Alright, I will!

Comment: @Alex by the way, what compiler are you using? I tried the code with `clang`, `msvc` and `gcc`. While `clang` and `msvc` automatically warn that you use `%d`, but input a float, `gcc` does not. You have to enable warnings with `-Wall` in `gcc` first.

Comment: @jan.sende I compile on Windows in visual studio with default compiler

Comment: @Alex Interesting! Did you get a warning? If not, enable them using the `/W4` commandline option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
printf("%d\n", y[i]);
```

`%d` expects an `int`, but you pass it a `float` -> **undefined behavior**, anything can happen. Use `%f` instead.

In C++, consider using IO streams instead of the C stdio functions.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I just spent an hour trying to figure something so trivial out :( I will rename the topic so it would resemble the situation correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
printf("%d\n", x[i]);
printf("%d\n", y[i]);
}
```

%d in `printf` means that you're printing a int number, you should use %f instead.

Better yet, use std::cout, so you don't have to worry about such things.

At the top of file add `#include <iostream>`

And you can write

```
std::cout<<x[i]<<'\n';
std::cout<<y[i]<<'\n';
```

Comment: Your answer is also very welcomed!  Thank you for the input!